# Understanding a Proof Involving Swapping the Conditional Expectation

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, proof-explanation, conditional-expectation

This is a follow up from a previous question: [Changing the order of Conditional Expectation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4800128/changing-the-order-of-conditional-expectation/4800205#4800205).

The reason I asked this question earlier is due to part of a proof that I am trying to understand. In particular, I am trying to understand the second equality. To my understanding, at this line, we should have $\mathbb{E}_g(\| g \|_\infty \mathbb{E}_X \mathbb{E}_\epsilon \| \sum_{i = 1} ^N \epsilon_i X_i \|)$ instead of the the other way around. It seems like the author is claiming this follows from independence, but I am not sure why:

[image]

[image]

**Here is the definition of the subscripts under expectation:**

[image]

**Here is the definition of the $\epsilon$ appeared in the proof and Theorem 6.7.1.:**

[image]

Comment: I assume the $\epsilon_i$ values have some unstated property that must be assumed, such as being either $-1$ or $1$ (which will get you past the first line). The second line of the proof seems to be justified by some unknown "Theorem 6.7.1."

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. I updated my post to include these information. In particular, I am asking about the third line of the chain of equality and inequalities.

Comment: Usually people assume Bernoulli variables are in $\{0,1\}$. Are they assuming the $\epsilon$ variables are in $\{0,1\}$ or in $\{-1,1\}$?  I think the "symmetry" argument of the Gaussians would only apply if $\epsilon_i\in\{-1,1\}$.

Comment: $\epsilon$ variables are assumed to be the Rademacher random sign. Taking $-1, 1$ with $1/2$ probability.

Comment: In that case your Theorem 6.7.1 is assuming everything is deterministic except the random $\epsilon_i$ variables. So its application for line 2 of that proof is to outer-condition on $X, g$ so that those are treated as deterministic when applying Theorem 6.7.1, in particular $$E[Z] = E[ E[Z|(X,g)]]$$

Comment: So this issue seems to have nothing to do with "changing the order of conditional expectation" as you linked to. It is a concept of "iterated expectations" $E[W]=E[E[W|Z]]$.

Comment: @Michael I am not sure if we are addressing the same problem. I am asking about the line following immediate after the line using Theorem 6.7.1. -- The line where the author used independence. I do not see how this follow from the iterated expectation of conditional expectations.

Comment: I do not know what they mean by those subscripts on the expectations, it seems informal. I would write that step this way (where $h, g$ are measurable functions and $G, X, \epsilon$ are random vectors): $$E[h(G)E[f(\epsilon, X)|X,G]]\overset{(a)}{=} E[h(G)E[f(\epsilon,X)|X]] \overset{(b)}{=} E[h(G)]E[E[f(\epsilon, X)|X]]=E[h(G)]E[f(\epsilon,X)]$$ where (a) uses $E[f(\epsilon, X)|X,G]=E[f(\epsilon, X)|X]$ because $G$ is independent of $(\epsilon, X)$; (b) uses the fact that every function of $G$ is independent of every function of $X$.

Comment: @Michael I assume you meant $G$ is the Gaussian vector and $h$ is the infinity norm? I think the computation you wrote down makes so much more sense to me. If you want to make this an answer, I will accept it right away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I would get from line 2 to line 3. Let $G, X, \epsilon$ be mutually independent random vectors. We can consider $f(\epsilon, X)$ and $h(G)$ for some measurable functions $f, h$. Now, assuming all expectations are finite, we get

\begin{align}
E[h(G)E[f(\epsilon, X)|(X,G)]] &\overset{(a)}{=}E[h(G)E[f(\epsilon, X)|X]] \\
&\overset{(b)}{=}E[h(G)]\: E[E[f(\epsilon, X)|X]]\\
&\overset{(c)}{=}E[h(G)] E[f(\epsilon, X)]
\end{align}
where

- Step (a) holds because $E[f(\epsilon, X)|(X,G)]=E[f(\epsilon, X)|X]$ since $G$ is independent of $(\epsilon, X)$;
- Step (b) holds because the conditional expectation $E[f(\epsilon, X)|X]$ is a measurable function of $X$, and every measurable function of $X$ is independent of every measurable function of $G$;
- Step (c) holds by iterated expectations.

You can use $h(G)=||G||_{\infty}$ and $f(\epsilon, X) = ||\sum_{i=1}^n \epsilon_iX_i||$.

---

In general I do not like the subscripts on expectations. I know they are usually used to make things simpler, but they can also make things more confusing. In this context, I do not really know what the definitions of those subscripts are (they seem to implicitly be conditional expectations given something). I like using standard iterated expectations like $E[X]=E[E[X|Y]]$.